# Tkinter 'label' widget - Newlines adding space randomly

Tags: python, tkinter, label, newline

I am trying to making a 'label' widget that contains help for my program. Assuming my label widget is called 'menu', I use:

```
menu['text'] = '1. \n2. \n3. \n4. \n5.'
```

This should output something like:

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
```

However, it outputs:

```
1.
 2.
  3.
   4.
5.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's not a speck of Tkinter code in this post. Your question would be better if you could show actual code that illustrates the problem, instead of making us guess.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `anchor` and `justify` options when creating your `Label`, like so:

`myLabel = Label(self, text='1. \n2. \n3. \n4. \n5.', anchor=W, justify=LEFT)`

`anchor=W` will position your text to the west (hence the `W`) inside the `Label`, while `justify=LEFT` will make sure any additional lines of text are left justified.

Comment: I suggest, besides, to use os.linesep instead of "\n"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Remove the empty spaces in your code. It seems to be just a matter of formatting inside the Python file.